# Angular proxy path rewrite not working during http get request call?

Tags: angular, proxy, cross-browser, odata

My proxy config not working as it is not redirecting as per rewrite config
Below is my proxy.config.json

```
{
    "/sap": {
        "target" : "http://server.domain.com:8002",
        "secure" : false,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/sap": ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }

}
```

Below is my http call
`this.http.get('/sap/opu/odata/sap/ABC_FD_SRV/ID_GEN_Set?sap-client=010', {headers}).pipe(map((response: any) => response));`

Headers used for the http request

```
var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json ');
        headers.append('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
```

Whenever i use `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json` to start and check in the networks tag instead of `http://server.domain.com:8002` it redirects to `http://localhost:4200`

i have tried with `/sap/*` but no use. Can anyone help me to solve this problem i am working out to call odata link to consume the data from the server so i have used `changeOrigin: true` for cross origin browser problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant that you only see `http://localhost:4200` in your Networks tab, it's OK. From the browser, it goes out as 4200. Proxying happens in your host server. What is the response to your call?

Comment: empty in  the response

Comment: If you don't get any errors, I would assume that your request found its destination. You already set `logLevel` to `debug`, which is very smart. In your console, when you started your server with `ng serve`, do you see any logs regarding path rewrite?

Comment: Ok. So, in your Networks tab, you see `localhost:4200` because that is what your Angular application sends. The call gets to your host server, which looks up rewrite rules from your `proxy.config.json`. It finds a matching rule, makes the rewrite and forwards the request. 

You should see a 404 response code if your rewrite didn't work. But you said that you don't get any errors, only an empty response (btw, is the response code 200?). So clearly it had to reach your server, I assume that your response is, in fact, empty because the server returns nothing.